# Why are my xlabels shown multiple times?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Edit: Thanks for helping me with my second concern and that admins put in my compiled code. It's compiled in another way for me, as I use Overleaf. This might be the source of my doubled labeling. I add a screenshot of it:

[image: Here you see how it looks for me in Overleaf (the x-axis has multiple PCK, PK and OK labels)]

I'm trying to build a stacked column chart with 4 labels on the x-axis. But they are shown multiple times if I increase the size with `width=0.7\linewidth`. How do I just show the x labels where the columns are?

Also, I didn't find any clue in the `pgfplot` manual about how to format and position "nodes near coords" but this is a second concern.

PS: This is my first plot in latex, so there might be some flaws, but I try my best ;)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.7\linewidth,
    ybar stacked, nodes near coords,
    bar width=30pt,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
   ylabel={Prevalence},
   xlabel={Category},
    symbolic x coords={CK, PCK, PK, OK}
   ]
\addplot coordinates {(CK,3) (PCK,13) 
  (PK,3) (OK,14)};
\addplot coordinates {(CK,6) (PCK,5) 
  (PK,3) (OK,3)};
\addplot coordinates {(CK,3) (PCK,2)
  (PK,1) (OK,3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Nice MWE (code example),

Comment: I added a screenshot of the output of your code. I fail to see the problem.

Comment: Edited my post with a screenshot of my visualization. As I work with overleaf, this might be the source of the problem, seeing your compiled version hasn't got the problem.

Comment: I also created the screenshot with overleaf, pdflatex 2021. See updated answer.

Comment: Mhh, but I literally used this code with pdflatex 2021. Another option would be that other packages are interfering with pgfplots, as there are many packages loaded.

Comment: Then you have to test this bit by bit on your side until you find which package/setting causes the problem. If the code that you provide does not show the problem then it is difficult to discuss it further. In general, it is good practice to test the code that you show in your question before publishing it. (all is meant friendly)

Comment: You can modify your question so that it only reflects the second part (which I try to answer below). Then take some time to formulate a new question (first part of the current question).

Comment: **To your edit:** Overleaf is not the problem since I also used Overleaf. You have to provide code that shows the actual problem. The code that you provide works fine using Overleaf (pdflatex, 2021). As of now, *your question cannot be answered* because the relevant information is missing.

Comment: Yes I will test it thouroghly and bit by bit. And yes, I will test my next contributed codes in a separate file first :) I'm really glad, that someone is helping me with this, as it's quite hard to get a foothold with plots. It's my second document in Latex and already my master thesis, so it got complicated quite fast. Anyway, I will test different packages tomorrow as it is 3am in Germany... But thank you so much for your help, Dr. Kühner :)

Comment: Good luck (Viel Glück)! Creating plots takes a long time. For me, I often need 4 hours to create a single plot until I am happy with it.

Comment: See the new promising answer! Maybe it was just the different line width that made the MWE work fine :). You can use `xtick=data` (and accept the new answer)

Comment: Unfortunately your (second) question about formatting and positioning `nodes-near-coords` is a bit vague. So please either be more detailed and/or add a sketch of what you want to achieve. Alternatively/additionally you could search for some answers/questions with the tag [tag:nods-near-coords].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the key-value-pair `xtick=data` does the trick - alternatively you can specify `xtick={CK, PCK, PK, OK}` or leave some of the `symbolic x coords` empty:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=\linewidth,
    ybar stacked, 
    nodes near coords,
    bar width=30pt,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    ylabel={Prevalence},
    xlabel={Category},
%    symbolic x coords={CK,, PCK,, PK,, OK},
    symbolic x coords={CK, PCK, PK, OK},
    xtick=data
%    xtick={CK, PCK, PK, OK}
   ]
\addplot coordinates {(CK,3) (PCK,13) 
  (PK,3) (OK,14)};
\addplot coordinates {(CK,6) (PCK,5) 
  (PK,3) (OK,3)};
\addplot coordinates {(CK,3) (PCK,2)
  (PK,1) (OK,3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Answer to the *second part of your question* (how to format `nodes near coords`), use `nodes near coords style`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.7\linewidth,
    ybar stacked, 
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style = {font = \huge, yshift = 2pt}, % <-- Added
    bar width=30pt,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    ylabel={Prevalence},
    xlabel={Category},
    symbolic x coords={CK, PCK, PK, OK}
   ]
\addplot coordinates {(CK,3) (PCK,13) 
  (PK,3) (OK,14)};
\addplot coordinates {(CK,6) (PCK,5) 
  (PK,3) (OK,3)};
\addplot coordinates {(CK,3) (PCK,2)
  (PK,1) (OK,3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Compiled with Overleaf* (see top right corner, "Menu" button)

[image]

[image]